# Routing with Mapbox Directions

Tags: mapbox, routing, mapbox-gl-js

I´ve built my own mapstyle and mapsource on Mapbox. After that I included the Directions Plugin in my HTML-Site. Works so far.

Problem is the Directions Plugin don´t use my own Line-Elements for the routes. I think the routign is based on the standard-map from Mapbox...

How can i change that?

Answer (score 2):

> But how can the routing work when leaflet only displays tiles as a raster-Format?

Because routing information is vectorial, not raster. When you make a query to any of the [Leaflet Routing Machine](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/) backends, the data coming back is vector data.

Routing information does not depend in any way on the data (or basemaps, or WMS layers, or whatever) being shown on your map.